# Comparing functions' smoothness

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, definition

I have a question about smoothness concept. by the definition on wikipedia:

> the smoothness of a function is a property measured by the number of derivatives it has which are continuous. A smooth function is a function that has derivatives of all orders everywhere in its domain.

Now, my question is how we measure and compare the degree of smoothness? for example I have function $f(x)= e^{-\alpha x}$. I plotted the function for different $\alpha$'s in MATLAB and it is shown below.

[image]

As $\alpha$ increases $x$ reaches 0 sooner(The blue plot obtained when $\alpha = 1$ and purple obtained when $\alpha = 200$ . Now, based on my understanding as we getting closer to a flat line we consider having a smoother function. As a result I should assume as $\alpha$ increases the function f(x) is smoother. But visually it looks less smooth to me ( it looks like two perpendicular lines).

Could any one help please to understand how should I compare two functions in terms of smoothness? visually or by a measurable criteria.

Thanks in advance.

---

Added [picture](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/) for further discussion

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The family of functions $f(x)=\operatorname{e}^{-\alpha x}$ are all essentially the same in terms of smoothness. Namely, they are all smooth, since they can be differentiated infinitely often. The only difference between the graphs is, in a sense, how fast the $x$-values are traversed, since $x$ is multiplied by the factor $\alpha$.

By adjusting the ratio between the axes, you can make the purple graph look exactly like the blue graph. Hence the visual appearance of the purple graph is merely due to the compression of smooth data due to aspect ratio changes.

---

The problem with such a visual approach is that smoothness is an infinitesimal property, so it only applies if you cannot "zoom in" to a an extend that will make the curve look smooth on that scale.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If you don't mind could you please look at the picture I added in the original post. the picture is from machine learning class. In the discussion it discussed as $\sigma$ get larger it is getting smoother.  Then how can I explain this. Am I totally wrong to compare this two problem?

Comment: @Crimson: I think you are comparing two different contexts for using the concept of smoothness. One is smoothness in a colloquial sense as in describing the visual appearance of a shape, as in that machine learning example. The formal definition of smoothness is more subtle, though, and cannot be determined visually, since it is, as I said, an infinitesimal property of a curve which only holds or breaks down if it is found to do so on that level.

Comment: I am sorry for asking too many questions. Does it mean in this ML lecture it  also talked about smoothness in a colloquial sense?

Comment: I rechecked the video and It says "for larger $\sigma^2$ it is a smoother function, varies more smoothly. " so may be it really different from the smoothness I try to understand. Thanks again.

Comment: @Crimson: I think it must be a different meaning in the video, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing smoothness and decay. As $\alpha$ increases, the function $f(x) = e^{-\alpha x}$ has stronger decay as $x\to \infty$, but the smoothness of the function doesn't change, at least not qualitatively, because it has infinitely many continuous derivatives regardless of the value of $\alpha$. Quantitatively, you could say the function becomes less smooth because the [modulus of continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity) satisfied by $f$ and its derivatives will become weaker.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree, I got confused. I've just learned about smoothness in different context and made some conclusions by myself. Unfortunately, I have not enough background to completely understand discussion in real analysis. I assumed maybe there is some strong relation between decay rate and level of smoothness.